# Tengo este codigo y me da el siguiente error

Tags: php, base-de-datos, php7, php5

ERROR -> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in.....
Creo que tiene que ver con la version de php pero no estoy seguro, se supone que este codigo funciona bien en la version 5 de php pero ya he intentado arreglarlo de varias maneras y aun no consigo que funcione por favor ayuda.

CODIGO

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234");
$consulta_noticias = "SELECT * FROM empleados";
$rs_noticias = mysqli_query($con,$consulta_noticias);
$num_total_registros = mysql_num_rows($rs_noticias);
```

//Si hay registros

```
if ($num_total_registros > 0) {
    //Limito la busqueda
    $TAMANO_PAGINA = 5;
        $pagina = false;
 
    //examino la pagina a mostrar y el inicio del registro a mostrar
        if (isset($_GET["pagina"]))
            $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
        
    if (!$pagina) {
        $inicio = 0;
        $pagina = 1;
    }
    else {
        $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
    }
```

````
//calculo el total de paginas
$total_paginas = ceil($num_total_registros / $TAMANO_PAGINA);



//oreder by fecha 
$consulta1 = "SELECT cod, nombre, apellido FROM empleados";


$consulta = "SELECT cod, nombre, apellido,estado FROM empleados ORDER BY cod ASC LIMIT ".$inicio."," . $TAMANO_PAGINA;
$rs = mysql_query($consulta, $con);
```
````

```
$hora = date('H:i:s a');
$fecha = date('d-m-Y ');
$aaaa= date('Y');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que al hacer la conexión a la base de datos te está faltando el nombre de la base de datos

```
//tu codigo
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234");

//agregando la base da datos al metodo mysqli_connect()
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234","mi_bdd");

//utilizando el metodo mysql_select_db()
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234");
mysql_select_db("mi_bdd", $con);
```

También el orden de los parámetros en `mysqli_query()` están al revés según con la documentación de PHP

```
//tu codigo pasando como primer parámetro la conexión en lugar de la query
$consulta_noticias = "SELECT * FROM empleados";
$rs_noticias = mysqli_query($con,$consulta_noticias);
$num_total_registros = mysql_num_rows($rs_noticias);

//la consulta como primer parámetro y luego el parametro $con
$consulta_noticias = "SELECT * FROM empleados";
$rs_noticias = mysqli_query($consulta_noticias,$con);
$num_total_registros = mysql_num_rows($rs_noticias);
```

Este ejemplo es de la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-num-rows.php) oficial de PHP

```
<?php

$enlace = mysql_connect("localhost", "usuario_mysql", "contraseña_mysql");
mysql_select_db("basedatos", $enlace);

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla1", $enlace);
$número_filas = mysql_num_rows($resultado);

echo "$número_filas Filas\n";

?>
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda logro resolver mi problema, muy amable por tomarse el tiempo de responder